# Joining data in Scala using array_contains() method

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have below data in Scala in Spark environment -

```
val abc = Seq(
  (Array("A"),0.1),
  (Array("B"),0.11),
  (Array("C"),0.12),
  (Array("A","B"),0.24),
  (Array("A","C"),0.27),
  (Array("B","C"),0.30),
  (Array("A","B","C"),0.4)
).toDF("channel_set", "rate")

abc.show(false)
abc.createOrReplaceTempView("abc")

val df = abc.withColumn("totalChannels",size(col("channel_set"))).toDF()
df.show()

scala> df.show
+-----------+----+-------------+
|channel_set|rate|totalChannels|
+-----------+----+-------------+
|        [A]| 0.1|            1|
|        [B]|0.11|            1|
|        [C]|0.12|            1|
|     [A, B]|0.24|            2|
|     [A, C]|0.27|            2|
|     [B, C]| 0.3|            2|
|  [A, B, C]| 0.4|            3|
+-----------+----+-------------+



val oneChannelDF = df.filter($"totalChannels" === 1)
oneChannelDF.show()
oneChannelDF.createOrReplaceTempView("oneChannelDF")

+-----------+----+-------------+
|channel_set|rate|totalChannels|
+-----------+----+-------------+
|        [A]| 0.1|            1|
|        [B]|0.11|            1|
|        [C]|0.12|            1|
+-----------+----+-------------+


val twoChannelDF = df.filter($"totalChannels" === 2)
twoChannelDF.show()
twoChannelDF.createOrReplaceTempView("twoChannelDF")

+-----------+----+-------------+
|channel_set|rate|totalChannels|
+-----------+----+-------------+
|     [A, B]|0.24|            2|
|     [A, C]|0.27|            2|
|     [B, C]| 0.3|            2|
+-----------+----+-------------+
```

I want to join oneChannel and twoChannel dataframes so that  I can see my resultant data as below -

```
+-----------+----+-------------+------------+-------+
|channel_set|rate|totalChannels|channel_set | rate  |
+-----------+----+-------------+------------+-------+
|        [A]| 0.1|            1|     [A,B]  |  0.24 |
|        [A]| 0.1|            1|     [A,C]  |  0.27 |
|        [B]|0.11|            1|     [A,B]  |  0.24 |
|        [B]|0.11|            1|     [B,C]  |  0.30 |
|        [C]|0.12|            1|     [A,C]  |  0.27 |
|        [C]|0.12|            1|     [B,C]  |  0.30 |
+-----------+----+-------------+------------+-------+
```

Basically I need all the rows where a record from oneChannel dataframe in present in twoChannel dataframe.

I have tried -

```
spark.sql("""select * from oneChannelDF one inner join twoChannelDF two on array_contains(one.channel_set,two.channel_set)""").show()
```

However, I am facing this error -

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'array_contains(one.`channel_set`, two.`channel_set`)' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be an array followed by a value of same type as the array members; line 1 pos 62;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I figured out the error. I need to pass a member as an argument to the array_contains() method. Since the size of every element in channel_set column for oneChannelDF is 1, hence below code gets me the correct data frame.

```
scala> spark.sql("""select * from oneChannelDF one inner join twoChannelDF two where array_contains(two.channel_set,one.channel_set[0])""").show()
+-----------+----+-------------+-----------+----+-------------+
|channel_set|rate|totalChannels|channel_set|rate|totalChannels|
+-----------+----+-------------+-----------+----+-------------+
|        [A]| 0.1|            1|     [A, B]|0.24|            2|
|        [A]| 0.1|            1|     [A, C]|0.27|            2|
|        [B]|0.11|            1|     [A, B]|0.24|            2|
|        [B]|0.11|            1|     [B, C]| 0.3|            2|
|        [C]|0.12|            1|     [A, C]|0.27|            2|
|        [C]|0.12|            1|     [B, C]| 0.3|            2|
+-----------+----+-------------+-----------+----+-------------+
```